# SSAS Tabular 2017 - Processing latest partition is successful but the data disappears

Tags: ssas-tabular

I'm running into a maddening problem processing a particular model in SSAS (Tabular)

I have a Fact table partitioned by date, and every hour a job setup to refresh the current partition.  The majority of the time this is working fine and the partition is updated, but occasionally (maybe once or twice a day right now) it will report that the processing was successful, but when I go look at the data in a report no data from that partition is viewable.  If I simply rerun the the same processing job it magically comes back.

I've had our DBA monitoring the server resources to see if we're having memory issues/contention/errors but so far haven't seen anything out of the ordinary.  Wondering if anyone has ever seen something like this and what solutions come to mind.

Comment: What granularity is your "current" partition? Week? Day? Hour?
Are you sure, that you have data in your source at the processing start? Maybe the underlying process truncate your table and repopulate it?

Comment: The current partition contains all facts for the current year.  The data behind the scenes is only added to, not deleted/recreated.

Comment: OK. To get depth into, you should use Extende events "Progress Report End". Progress Report End events will tell you the start time, end time, and duration for each of the major components (e.g. dimensions, measure groups, partitions, etc) down to the various phases of processing for each major component (e.g. Execute SQL, Read Data, Write Data, Build Decode, Build Index, Compress Segment, etc)

The second one is "Progress Report Error" (It is possible that it will catch the error)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175667.aspx#Anchor_1

Comment: Can you share the code which processes the current partition?

Answer (score 0):

We have recently encountered a very similar problem: fact table current partition with 0 rows after normal SSAS Tabular model processing.

What we found is that there were two jobs working simultaneously with the same table: one job loaded data (data was first deleted and then inserted) and the other processed the above-mentioned model. It is possible that processing job accessed the table exactly at the moment when data had already been deleted and had not been loaded back yet.

So I disabled processing job schedule and added a step to the loading job so that the processing started strictly after data load is completed.